# Oracle UTL_TCP to Graylog GELF TCP error - GELF message is too short. Not even the type header would fit

Tags: oracle, graylog2, gelf

I am facing an issue when trying to send data from Oracle via UTL_TCP to Graylog GELF TCP.

I try with a single event (record, JSON formatted, as per Graylog required). The issue consists in the fact that while the single event does upload correctly, I get 45 Graylog internal events generated too, evidently related to two of them:

```
.....
"2018-12-18T14:13:33.938Z","graylog-server","runit-service","true","6","ERROR [NettyTransport] Error in Input [GELF TCP/5c119b1eb358cb056b417b89] (channel [id: 0x1957cea0, /192.168.1.22:49550 :> /192.168.1.74:41000])"
.....
"2018-12-18T14:13:33.959Z","graylog-server","runit-service","true","6","java.lang.IllegalStateException: GELF message is too short. Not even the type header would fit."
.....
```

The PL SQL code I use in Oracle is as below:

```
create or replace procedure AAA_GRAYLOG_TCP_05
is

conn                utl_tcp.connection;
v_GL_record         clob;
ret_val             pls_integer;

v_lms_host          varchar2(4000) := '192.168.1.74';
v_lms_port          number := 41000;

begin

v_GL_record := 
'{ "version": "1.1", "host": "dataplus05", "short_message": "A short message", "level": 5, "_some_info": "foo" }' 
;

dbms_output.put_line(v_GL_record);

conn := utl_tcp.open_connection(
remote_host => v_lms_host, 
remote_port => v_lms_port
);
ret_val := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(conn, v_GL_record);
utl_tcp.close_connection(conn);

end;
```

I tried adding some:

```
\"0", or \0, after the last }
```

to the end of the v_GL_record but to no avail. I still have the 45 extra records, and the ERROR and Java.IllegalState generated

Tried also to put the same backslash-zeros instead of default CL-FR, when opening connection:

```
conn := utl_tcp.open_connection(
remote_host => v_lms_host, 
remote_port => v_lms_port,  
newline => '\0'
);
```

still the same problem.

can someone help?

best regards,

Altin

The list of Graylog internal messages:

[graylog extra internal messages](https://pastebin.com/cuWK4jZq)

Comment: Try specifying `charset` explicitly as `AL32UTF8` (should make no difference but good practice regardless) and setting `newline` to `CHAR(0)`. I'm fairly certain that using `\0` is just going to get you a "newline" that consists of a ``\`` and a `0` character. If that doesn't work, try adding the `CHAR(0)` to your string and using `WRITE_TEXT` instead of `WRITE_LINE`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jeroen Mostert.

The internal messages disappeared when opening the connection with the newline set to chr(0) 

conn := utl_tcp.open_connection(
remote_host => v_lms_host, 
remote_port => v_lms_port,
newline => Chr(0)
);

Thank you very much for the chr(0).

One more thing please. I have not used the charset parameter, since  the first 256 chars returned by chr(x) will be always the same in all charsets.
Am I correct on my assumption?

best regards,
Altin

Comment: The Graylog protocol specifies UTF-8, so this becomes relevant as soon as you try sending over characters that aren't in ASCII (like €). While those may not be occurring any time soon in your logs, why risk it?

Comment: It happened precisely how you predicted.
In a non Unicode DB (NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252), the  € will be lost to some asterisk-kind in Graylog and (!) escaped x\800 in Splunk.
I mean using the default NULL charset in UTL_TCP.Open_connection, which (I think) is using the DB's charset and not the ASCII.

Comment: But, one knows what character-set uses in Oracle and what to expect. So if one would need the unicode, he would have set that before as a DB setting. And when the charset is omitted in the UTL_TCP.Open_connection - it will set as unicode - as DB default.

So how do you think the best practice to be:
omit the charset at UTL_TCP.Open_connection ?
or
force it as AL32UTF8 ?

I tried the the later with my western charset, and it was fine, did transmitted the € character .

Is it that an any X -> AL32UTF8  will not harm in anyway?

best regards
Altin

Comment: The `charset` parameter specifies the character set to use when sending the string over the wire, and for Graylog, the correct setting for that is `AL32UTF8`. Whatever the original character set in the DB is doesn't matter, since the data will be converted. Since UTF-8 can represent every character in Unicode, there is no character in any other encoding that can't be transmitted this way.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir.

I am gone keep using the charset. I can have it NULL each time I like.

I now think that you must group the charset parameter usage advise for UTL_TCP.TCP Open_Connection, and also the newline one (Chr(0)),
in a new Answer (not comment) so that I can accept it as such.

Correct?

thank you very very much

best regards
Altin